# adjust horizontal spacing in array environment

Tags: math-mode, equations, arrays

Please consider the following simple example:

```
\begin{array}{rcl}
    a&=&b
\end{array}
```

If I use this, then the horizontal spacing between "a" and "=" and the horizontal spacing between "=" and $b$ is too large. I would like this spacing to be as large as it is in $a=b$. Is that possible?

Comment: don't use àrray to typeset equations use amsmath alignments `\begin{aligned} a&=b \end{aligned}` has the right spacing

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you (a) set the length parameter `\arraycolsep` to 0pt (default: 5pt) and (b) replace the `c` column type with `C`, where `C` is defined via a `\newcolumntype` directive; see below.

This approach works with operators of type `mathrel` (such as `=`) and with operators of type `mathbin` (such as `+`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\begin{array}{rClCl}
    a &=& b &+& c \\
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{a=b+c}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
You can compare
\arraycolsep=1.3pt\def\arraystretch{1.05}
$\begin{array}{rcl}
    a&=&b
\end{array}$
with this
$a=b$
\end{document}
```

[image]